# Where to use add data-secret in Stripe React Elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm following this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/billing#storing-payment-methods

 And it tells me to use the data-secret like this:

```
<input id="card-holder-name" type="text">

<!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
<div id="card-element"></div>

<button id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
    Update Payment Method
</button>
```

I'm using React, and [React Stripe Elements](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements) in my project.

I created a route:`/api/clientsecret` to return the client_secret.
But I'm not quite sure where I will use the client_secret with [React Stripe Elements](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Stripe Elements is deprecated, you should use [React Stripe JS](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js) instead

Laravel is assuming you're doing server side rendering here, which isn't the case with React. You should just use `fetch` to grab the `client_secret` from that route you created when you are ready to confirm a SetupIntent.